# Conditions/Counterexample for equality/lower bound in Krull height theorem

Tags: commutative-algebra

I am looking for a counterexample to the following version of the Krull height theorem.

> Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian ring with $1$. Let $I := (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ be a finitely generated ideal with minimal generating set $\{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$ and let $P \in \operatorname{Spec}(R)$ with $I \subsetneq P$ minimal among all primes in $R$. Then $\operatorname{ht}(P) = n$.

Here "minimal generating set" is meant in the sense that $\forall i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}: (x_1, \ldots, x_{i-1}, x_{i+1}, \ldots, x_n) \subsetneq (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$.

i.e. I am looking for a prime $P$, which is minimal over $I$, whose height is strictly smaller than $n$.

The standard version of the Krull height theorem I am refering to is

> Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian ring with $1$. Let $I := (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ be a finitely generated ideal and let $P \in \operatorname{Spec}(R)$ with $I \subseteq P$ minimal among all primes in $R$. Then $\operatorname{ht}(P) \leq n$.

Also, under what more conditions does the theorem hold? or under what conditions can one give a lower bound $m$ for $\operatorname{ht}(P)$.

---

Comments:

- If we leave out the condition for $P$ to be *strictly* larger than $I$, then any minimally prime principal ideal will do since it is minimally prime over itself (having one generator), but has height $0$.
- If we leave out the condition of the generating set being minimal, then any $(x_1, \ldots, x_n, a)$ with $a \in (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ gives a counterexample since $P$ minimal over $(x_1, \ldots, x_n, a)$ implies $\operatorname{ht}(P) \leq n+1$, but $(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = (x_1, \ldots, x_n, a) \subsetneq P$ minimally, so $\operatorname{ht}(P) \leq n < n+1$.
- Under the stronger assumption of minimalism of the generating set meaning that there does not exist a set with strictly fewer elements over which $P$ is minimal then the statement is correct. Assume that $P$ is minimal over $I$, but has height strictly smaller than $n$. Then that is a contradiction to minimality of the generating set by the converse of Krull height theorem.

Comment: I think [tag:dimension-theory] is intended to be used for questions about topological and/or fractal dimensions only. This is an ok question about commutative algebra, though.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen That’s fair. How about the krull-dimension tag? I’d think it’s closest to questions about height.

Comment: There are one dimensional local Noetherian rings $R_n$ with maximal ideal generated by any given $n>0$. This will give you easy counterexamples.

Comment: @Mohan that is helpful, but I don’t think it gives an example in which the prime is strictly greater

Comment: It does. Take such a ring and take $n-1$ elements of the $n$ generators. The ideal generated is clearly strictly contained in the maximal ideal, which is the only non-zero prime and thus minimal.

Comment: @Mohan I’m sorry, how does one know that the maximal ideal is the only non $0$ prime ideal? If the ring were an integral domain $(0)$ were prime and dimension would give the claim.

Comment: You can find domains with the property. Here is a standard example. $R_n=k[[t^n, t^{n+1},\ldots, t^{2n-1}]]$.

Comment: Nice example. Thank you very much